# Blazor state management with web history API

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, blazor, html5-history

I'm working with blazor server app on .NET Core 3.1. I'm trying to store an object on the browser history state by using [history web api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API/Working_with_the_History_API) with blazor JS interop. Then I can read that object once user click back button.

JavaScript function:

```
function setStateObject(stateObj) {
    window.history.pushState(stateObj, "");
}
```

blazor code:

```
public async Task SetHistoryItem()
{
    await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("setStateObject", stateObj);
}
```

I need to call `SetHistoryItem()` method just before route change on the app. I have tried with `NavigationManager.LocationChanged` event and with `dispose()` method.

```
private void OnLocationChanged(object sender, LocationChangedEventArgs args)
{
    base.InvokeAsync(async () =>
    {
         await SetHistoryItem();
    });
}

public void Dispose()
{
    base.InvokeAsync(async () =>
    {
         await SetHistoryItem();
    });
}
```

but on that both cases route has been already changed. So `history.back` won't send `stateObj`. Is there any solution that I can invoke `SetHistoryItem()` method just before route change on the blazor component.

Comment: This is one of the most requested features on github. See this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/14962).